# how to pass generated data from a database to an array in codeigniter

Tags: forms, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, helper

This is my model --->

```
 public function listminister()
{
$this->db->where('minstat', '1'); 
$query = $this->db->get('minister');
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
return $query->result();
}
}
```

I would like to utilize the codeigniter's form helper's `drop_down()`

base on the the model above i would like to generate a code like this in my view.

```
    $options = array(
                  'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
                  'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
                );


echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'defaultvalue');
```

the options value are from my database. i would like to generate a code like this.....

```
$options = array(
                  'value1'  => 'Small Shirt',
                  'value2'    => 'Medium Shirt',
                  'value3'   => 'Large Shirt',

                );


echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, 'defaultvalue');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

**In your Model :**

```
public function listminister(){
      $this->db->where('minstat', '1'); 
      $query = $this->db->get('minister');
      $result = array('' => 'Select ministat');
      foreach($query->result_array() as $opt){
         $result[$opt['your_value_column']] = $opt['name']           
      }
      return $result; 
}
```

**In controller  :**

```
public function index(){
   $this->load->helper('form');
   $data['options'] = $this->model_name->listminister();
   $this->load->view('your_view',$data);
}
```

**in view**

```
 echo form_dropdown('shirts', $options, '');
```